# In Django, how to know which button was pressed?

Tags: python, html, django

Here is my html, I have two buttons, one for accepting and the other for rejecting the request. In my view, I need to know which button was pressed along with the email of the applicant (tutor_application.tutor.chalkslateuser.email). I tried many solutions but to no avail.

```
{% for tutor_application in tutor_application_list %}

    <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
      <img src="{{ tutor_application.tutor.picture.url }}" class="card-img-top" >
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
            {{ tutor_application.tutor.chalkslate_user.first_name }} {{ tutor_application.tutor.chalkslate_user.last_name }}
        </h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ tutor_application.note }}</h6>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ tutor_application.posted }}</h6>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-success" role="button" type="submit"> Accept </a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="#" role="button"> Reject </a>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are trying to implement this manually rather than using [Django's form framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)?

Comment: No reason other than that I understand forms as being something to fill in. These cards just require approval or rejection. Do you suggest enclosing it inside form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Info

Lets split the layers to avoid confusions like that. There is 2 layers, **Client Side** and **Server Side**

#### Server Side

Django works on server side, he fetch the data from variables that you have sended to your page with all other things, so in general he will **mount one HTML page** and return it to your client (in that case you)

#### Client Side

This is the page that was returned by django (or any other server or framework) this running on clients browser not in server, that is called DOM, and django cant manipulate it because is already rendered, to do it you will need to use **Javascript** so you can interact with elements from your page, fire events and see if any data was changed in client side, one easy way to use Javascript on client side is using Jquery because is one library more friendly

Here is your code with slightly change, i added names and id to your both links, called than btnAccept and btnReject and added `<input type="hidden" id="btnType" name="btnType">`

```
{% for tutor_application in tutor_application_list %}

    <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
      <img src="{{ tutor_application.tutor.picture.url }}" class="card-img-top" >
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
            {{ tutor_application.tutor.chalkslate_user.first_name }} {{ tutor_application.tutor.chalkslate_user.last_name }}
        </h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ tutor_application.note }}</h6>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ tutor_application.posted }}</h6>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="btnType">
      <a id="btnAccept" name="btnAccept" class="btn btn-outline-success" role="button" type="submit"> Accept </a>
      <a id=="btnReject" name="btnReject" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="#" role="button"> Reject </a>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Here some code with Jquery to manipulate it in front if you want to do that in client side

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    $("#btnAccept").click(function(){
        $("#btnType").val('accepted');
    });

    $("#btnReject").click(function(){
        $("#btnType").val('rejected');
    });
});
```

**So in your post data just check the value from btnType and see if was accepted or rejected**

Or just add the tag names in your inputs (as i did before) and you can get it from your request data... you should change tag  to  and just get it in your backend as you clicked on it

#### EDIT

All your data from you form will be at `request.POST` (if you send it as POST), so you can get it as `request.POST['email']` (**that is kinda dirty, because if you dont have email in POST will raise a error**), or better approach that is `request.POST.get('email', None)`, thats try get the attribute called email, if dont find it will just return None (null), so you can validate it with if or something like it

About your object `tutor_application`, when you render your template using tutor_application.tutor.chalkslateuser.email that will be just the email as string, so you not hold the reference of the objects when you send it to the frontend, so if you want to know what tutor is selected you might have to **add id or email as input in your html** so you can send it back to the backend and figureout what tutor is

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{tutor_application.tutor.chalkslateuser.email}}">
```

And in your backend you get it as

```
email = request.POST.get('email', None')
```

Keep in mind to change your `<a>` tags to `<input name="">` so you can get it in your backend as attributes in **request.POST**

Comment: How do I send objects like tutor_application.tutor.chalkslateuser.email to my view? And can I distinguish buttons without JQuery?

Comment: You can have multiple buttons in your view as type submit, when you click on it he will send only that button, so you can check if there is first or second button in request data

Comment: To send objects like tutor_application and etc... in your view you should add it in the context, or you can just add locals() to your return, so you can pass all variables inside that view to your template, for security purposes is better to you set by yourself what you want to send to your template, so adding each variable to context

Comment: No, I want to send from my template to my view (not the other way around). This is because not only do I need to know which button was pressed, I also need to know which card the button was associated with. So, I need to send this object,  tutor_application.tutor.chalkslateuser.email.

Comment: When you send data from your view to template, is all text, so you lose the reference of the object, its just string, what you can do is pass the data to some input hidden so  you can send it back to the backend, i would recommend id and do some validations if anyone try to change it manualy inspecting the html in browser

Comment: all your data form your form is here ´request.POST´ you can access request.POST['email'] that is bad approach because if you dont have it from your template will raise a error, best way is using like that request.POST.get('email', None), so if the attribute is not found they set it as None, and you check if is None or no

Comment: If the tutor is already registered in your backend, you can place the Tutor Id in your template with some input hidden so you can send it back to your backend, and there you can access his Email... or instead of using id (more safe) you can just send the email and get it back <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{tutor_application.tutor.chalkslateuser.email}}">

Comment: keep in mind you must change your <a> tags to <input> tags, only that way you can get it in your backend

Comment: Could you post the last 3 comments as a separate answer so that I could mark it as correct answer.
I followed your steps but used buttons after enclosing the card in <form>. And I used id instead of email.

Comment: i can EDIT the post and add the extra info

Answer (score 0):

Do use Django Forms framework! Absolutely, definitely, do.

However, there is no reason not to have two submit buttons for one Django form/page. These have a name and a value. For example

```
<input type="submit name="update" value="Update" 
     class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-update" />

<input type="submit" name="done" value="Done" 
     class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-done" />
```

In your view, you can look in `request.POST` to see which was pressed. For example,

```
if request.POST.get('done', None):
     # user pressed the Done button
```

Comment: does the first parameter take name as argument? My view also needs an email address to identify which card was handled. How do I send objects like tutor_application.tutor.chalkslateuser.email to my view?

Comment: Data from an end user is evil and needs to be validated through a Django form. To reveive an email address use an EmailField.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield